# What is correct order to AddCors into .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

First MVC middleware or Cors Middleware.

```
    services.AddMvc()
    services.AddCors();
```

Sorry official doc mentions above however I have seen other examples with reverse order working fine as well.

> Could you share a glimple on internals on how it works?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Services using AddX()

When registering services inside `ConfigureServices`, the order in which you call the `AddX()` methods usually does not matter. So you can order and logically group them in the way that makes most sense to you.

The only way the order would actually matter if there are multiple service registrations of the same type, in which case the latest registration would win. The default framework parts are usually not built in such a way though. Instead, they are actually built in a way that they can be called multiple times without a problem. This is especially useful when you want to reconfigure certain services later.

For `AddMvc()` and `AddCors()`, both methods will register a separate set of services, so there is really no difference when calling one earlier than the other.

Note that neither `AddMvc()` nor `AddCors()` actually set up any middleware. They just prepare the necessary services that the middlewares need in order to run. The middleware is configured inside of the `Configure` method.

#### Middleware using `app.UseX()`

The [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is configured in `Configure` and there the order in which you register each middleware *does* matter.

The middleware is a chained pipeline that runs in the order you register it:

[image: Middleware pipeline]

In order to have one middleware affect another middleware, it will need to execute around that other middleware. So in your case, since you want to enable CORS for the MVC middleware, so that you can properly request routes within MVC from other origins, you will need to register the CORS middleware *before* the MVC middleware.

You can also take a look at the [implementation of the CORS middleware](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v2.2.4/src/Middleware/CORS/src/Infrastructure/CorsMiddleware.cs#L183-L208). As you can see the call to `next()` is at the very end of it, so that means that the relevant logic of the CORS middleware runs before it executes the next middleware. That’s a good sign that it needs to run first.

So the correct order is:

```
app.UseCors();
app.UseMvc();
```

As a general rule, the MVC middleware almost always should come last.

Comment: I had asked for `services.AddMvc()
    services.AddCors();` however thanks for explaining `app.UseCors();
app.UseMvc();` Does the thumb rule `As a general rule, the MVC middleware almost always should come last.` applies for `app.Use***` or `services.Add***` please?

Comment: In short Use*** order matters or Add*** matters for the middle-ware execution / configuration pls.

Comment: @Abhijeet Oh sorry, I totally missed that part, since you were talking about “middleware” in your question. – I have added a part to my answer that talks explicitly about the service registrations :)

Comment: Paragraph 4, I believe, should read "...do **not** actually set up..."

Comment: @IanW _“neither A nor B do set up“_ is already negated with the _“neither”_.

Comment: @poke Interesting. To me the use of "do" is an addition that asserts the positive form of the statement, and contradicts the "neither".  Removing the "do" would make it read unambiguously to me.  I suppose that it depends on which side of the Atlantic we are reading it. (?) :-)

Comment: @IanW Hmm, I just removed the “do” now, hope that helps :D

Answer (score 3):

No, it's other way round. You should first add the CORS middle-ware before adding MVC middle-ware like below. Example taken from [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                "http://www.contoso.com");
        });
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

So does while using it

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins); 
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

If you read through the linked documentation it clearly says that

> Note:
>
> `UseCors` must be called before `UseMvc`.